# What are the advantages of Telerik Reporting over Crystal Reporting?

Tags: crystal-reports, telerik, telerik-reporting

I just need a list of advantages of using telerik over crystal. We may be moving to telerik from crystal soon?

Comment: search google.... This is not a site for listing advantages.. if you have any issue with the code.. post here for help

Comment: "*Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*" Have a look at [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)